# lightning:formattedText tag requires API version 41.0 and later

Tags: lightning-aura-components, gack

I used lightning tag called lightning:formattedText which requires Api version 41.0 or later.
This tag is used in a component whose Api verson is set to 41.0. Am I need to set the Api version of parent component to 41.0 or is it still have what ever version it has earlier?

Lets say Component A is the container which has Component B inside it.

lightning:formattedText tag is referenced inside Component B.
I've set Component B Api version to 41.0.
Do I need to update Component A's Api version now to make lightning:formattedText tag working.

Note: I'm unable to create a new version of package because of upgrading existing lightning component's Api version from 40.0 to 41.0. Component A is previously released and Component B is going to release now.

Answer (score 2):

For consistency and ease of debugging, salesforce recommend to set the same API version for all custom components in app.

Please see link [Don’t Mix Component API Versions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_ls_api_version_mix.htm)

Comment: +1 Good to see that's in the documentation at least. I've always been a strong supporter of not trying to mix API versions intentionally, because bugs can, and do, happen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a component that requires lightning:formattedText will also force all parent components to use at least version 41.0. This update will happen automatically, whether want it to or not.